# Redirect loop after .htaccess update

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect

I want my WordPress based homepage to automatically start at abc.com/#about if the user enters abc.com.

I have added the following to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=about 
RewriteRule ^$ /#about [L,R,NE]
```

The URL is changed, but the browser (chrome) give the error: “This webpage has a redirect loop”.

I get the same behavior if I use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/#about
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=#about
```

It could be because the URL contains a #, but I’m not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response!
The explanation from anubhava makes sense, but as a consequence it makes it hard to create a condition based on the URL that will stop the loop.
The cookie approach works fine and is now implemented! :-)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use cookies. You can set a cookie after redirecting to URI with # and then delete it. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|\s)test=1($|\s)
RewriteRule $ - [L,CO=test:0:.your_site.com:-1]
RewriteRule $ /#about [L,R,NE,CO=test:1:.your_site.com]
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that for the URL `http://domain.com/#about` browser doesn't send URI path after hash `#` to server and server will still see URL as `http://domain.com/` which will make it redirect again and eventually browser shows looping error to you.

You can try this rule to stop the looping:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html#about [L,NE,R]
```

OR else if `index.php` is your default file then:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php#about [L,NE,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=about 
RewriteRule $ /%23about [L,R,NE]
```

The `#` part is replaced with URL encoded form `%23`. and the part which has to be rewritten should be `$` , not `^$`

Comment: In my opinion, that doesn't work because the part of URI after # is not passed to the server.

Comment: here, user just enters `abc.com` (# is not there in the uri which user enters), we need to redirect to `abc.com/#about`